# Typeahead.js not showing async results

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I'm working on implementing typeahead.js in a search field and I'm having problems with async results only showing once in a while, while local results always work.

My suggestion backend returns data this JSON:

```
[{
    "query": "anders troelsen",
    "hits": "1197",
    "queryCount": "39"
},
{
    "query": "anders fogh jensen",
    "hits": "295",
    "queryCount": "38"
}]
```

In the code I want to transform the above JSON into an array of strings and then show it. This is the suggester code:

```
    var localSuggestResults = ["anders and", "anders ladekarl", "anders høg nissen"];

    var searchSuggestions = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        local: localSuggestResults,

        remote: {
            url: '/services/suggest?prefix=%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY',

            transform: function (suggestions) {
                var suggestionArray = suggestions.map(function(suggestion) {
                    return suggestion.query
                });

                return suggestionArray;
            }
        }

    });

    $("#query").typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    },
    {
        source: searchSuggestions
    });
```

Any suggestions for what I'm doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Any error your are getting?

Comment: No, nothing. The results are showing when I enter something with "anders" in this case, also the async results, but not if I search for any other term, even though they are received and transformed correctly

Comment: I think you need to init the engine? `searchSuggestions.initialize();`?

Comment: The engine is working, and I can console.log the results from it. But the results don't transfer to the typeahead suggestion window

Comment: @skovmand, are you using v0.11.1? 

It seems it has issues with remote source. I've logged a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515909 and wonder if you have found a workaround or logged a bug, please?

Also, if you could publish somewhere a page, that returns your JSON, that could help to code owners to reproduce the issue faster.

Answer (score 0):

it's late for response. but the library didn't change during this time.

asyncResult works when you set `{async:true}` in ajax options. set source to your own function that gets the result from server.